# Still logged in after deleting browsing history in IE9

Tags: windows, history, internet-explorer-9

When I try deleting browsing history from internet options in IE9, I am still logged in. For example, I'm still logged into my Super User account.

I also tried "disk cleanup" and there is no gain.

What can I do?

Comment: It may not be based on local storage, e.g. sessions.

Comment: Which OpenID are you using to log into SuperUser? You may be still logged in there (e.g. Google).

Comment: I have this problem in all sites, not only here with super user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have preserve favourites website data ticked (the top option when you go to delete history) I think this is a fantastic feature as it used to do my head in clearing Internet browser data but then having to re-enter all my passwords to my favourite sites I use often. Brilliant, Microsoft are really sorting there stuff out now, really impressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the browser, going to `Control Panel` > `Internet Options`, then clear it from there and relaunch.

Comment: And make sure you clear your __cookies__ not just your browsing history.

Comment: thanks, I tried it. deleting all the things, passwords, browsing history, cookies,... , but no result.

Comment: in a day, when I was opening a page my internet charge ran out and I had a warning page, after that day and after recharging I still have that warning page when I open that address.I dont know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in your Temporary Internet Files folder

Copy and paste this into Windows Explorer, delete the folders in there also. Edit it to include your user account name.

Simply trying to navigate to this hidden folder may not be possible but it will show it to you if you paste it into windows explorer bar.

```
C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5
```

Comment: You sure you are deleting IE cookies? Try this flash cookie remover also, a different type of persistent cookie...http://www.misec.net/flash-cookie-remover/

Comment: Yes for sure, I deleted all the files and folders in that address,